# How to refactor an insert stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, refactoring

Just need help taking this big chunk and making it as efficient as possible, I just started learning C# about 2 days ago so still very new to it. But I am writing code that uses an insert stored procedure from my SQL database.

Please also explain why your changes are efficient as well. I just started learning C# so I haven't written anything to connect to the front end of anything, I just thought it'd be cool to be able to write my inputs into the console app and still be able to use a stored procedure. Also one issue that I am facing is that, everything works until i get to the skills input, and it will just skip that part entirely.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SqlConnection PubsConn = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PeopleDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
            {


                SqlCommand testCMD = new SqlCommand("People_Insert", PubsConn);

                testCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter Id = testCMD.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 5);
                Id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                SqlParameter Title = testCMD.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                Title.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                SqlParameter Bio = testCMD.Parameters.Add("@Bio", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                Bio.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                SqlParameter Summary = testCMD.Parameters.Add("@Summary", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                Summary.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                SqlParameter Headline = testCMD.Parameters.Add("@Headline", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                Headline.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                SqlParameter Slug = testCMD.Parameters.Add("@Slug", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                Slug.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                SqlParameter StatusId = testCMD.Parameters.Add("@StatusId", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
                StatusId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                SqlParameter Skills = testCMD.Parameters.Add("@Skills", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                Skills.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                SqlParameter PrimaryImage = testCMD.Parameters.Add("@PrimaryImage", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                PrimaryImage.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                string titleInput;
                string bioInput;
                string summaryInput;
                string headlineInput;
                string slugInput;
                int statusId;
                string skillsInput;
                string imageInput;
                string strRowAffect;

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Title");
                titleInput = Console.ReadLine();
                Title.Value = titleInput;

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Bio");
                bioInput = Console.ReadLine();
                Bio.Value = bioInput;

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Summary");
                summaryInput = Console.ReadLine();
                Summary.Value = summaryInput;

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Headline");
                headlineInput = Console.ReadLine();
                Headline.Value = headlineInput;

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Unique Slug");
                slugInput = Console.ReadLine();
                Slug.Value = slugInput;

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a 1 digit Status Id");
                statusId = Console.Read();
                StatusId.Value = statusId;

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Skills");
                skillsInput = Console.ReadLine();
                Skills.Value = skillsInput;

                Console.WriteLine("Enter an Image Url");
                imageInput = Console.ReadLine();
                PrimaryImage.Value = imageInput;

                PubsConn.Open();

                strRowAffect = testCMD.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();

                Console.WriteLine("Number of Rows: " + strRowAffect);
                Console.WriteLine("Return Value: " + Id.Value);

            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what seems inefficient about your current code? what specifically is the problem? I guess you could skip the preliminary step of creating extra variables to hold user input, only to assign them to parameters (you could just assign the parameters directly from ReadLine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. There is no efficiency boost in my example, it's just a visual refactoring. Parameters have Input direction by default, so you don't need to set them explicitly.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var command = new SqlCommand("People_Insert");
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    var idParam = command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 5);
    idParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    var titleParam = command.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
    var bioParam = command.Parameters.Add("@Bio", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
    var summaryParam = command.Parameters.Add("@Summary", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
    var headlineParam = command.Parameters.Add("@Headline", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
    var slugParam = command.Parameters.Add("@Slug", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
    var statusIdParam = command.Parameters.Add("@StatusId", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
    var skillsParam = command.Parameters.Add("@Skills", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
    var primaryImageParam = command.Parameters.Add("@PrimaryImage", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);

    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Title");
    titleParam.Value = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Bio");
    bioParam.Value = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Summary");
    summaryParam.Value = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Headline");
    headlineParam.Value = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Unique Slug");
    slugParam.Value = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a 1 digit Status Id");
    statusIdParam.Value = Console.Read();

    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Skills");
    skillsParam.Value = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter an Image Url");
    primaryImageParam.Value = Console.ReadLine();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PeopleDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        var affectedRowsCount = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Console.WriteLine("Number of Rows: " + affectedRowsCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Return Value: " + idParam.Value);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Why not go one level further and do `command.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = Console.ReadLine();` and skip the extra variable declaration?

Comment: @RufusL that's not a bad idea, the code will look even shorter